# Modify the z-scale in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$},  axis on top, view={30}{30},zscale=0.5]
    \addplot3[surf,samples = 30,variable = \u,variable y = \v,
    domain = -pi:pi,y domain = -pi:pi]
    ({u}, {v}, {sin(deg(u))*cos(deg(v))});
    \addplot3[only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Generates this:

[image]

My question is very simple: there is a way to modify the z-scale and reduce, for example, by a factor equal to 0.5? How can I do this?

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like `z post scale=0.5` in your `axis` parameter. You can also do this with x and y axis. There are a lot more scaling options for `pgfplots`. For further information see the [manual](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) on page 293 Chapter 4.10.1 Common Scaling Options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[z post scale=0.5]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360,samples=40] 
        {sin(x)*sin(y)};    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

without z scale (or `z post scale=1`):

[image]

with z scale (`z post scale=0.5`):

[image]

scaling all 3 axis: (`z post scale=5,x post scale=2.2,y post scale=1.6`)

[image]